# array Length not reporting

Tags: javascript, arrays

This should be simple, but it doesnt make sense to me.
It is a simple section of a promise chain

```js
let flightName = [];
let guidArr = [];

Promise.all(guidArr)
       .then(values => {
         for(var a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
           Xrm.WebApi
              .online
              .retrieveRecord("crd80_flightplanevent", values[a], "?$select=_crd80_learnerflight_value")
              .then(
                function success(result) {
                  flightName.push(result["_crd80_learnerflight_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"])
                },
                function(error) {
                  DisplayError(error)
                }); 
         }
         return flightName
       }).then(flightName => {
         console.log(flightName) 
         console.log(flightName.length)         
         return flightName
       })
```

[image: Console log]

The console displays the flightName array correctly,
but flightName.length is always consoled as 0, even though console.log(flightName) puts length:2 as the output

Why???
I need to work with each item in the array but it is not recognised correctly

Comment: And which programming language is this in? I suspect it is Javascript but many of the C-like syntax languages have similar constructs so I've been wrong before.

Comment: Can you share a wider code snippet and an example input to flightName so we know what is going on here?

Comment: And also add the *exact*  output of that codesnippet

Comment: Yes it is javascript, sorry I should have said.
Code and output now added

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jabaa -  I was asked to add more code by tomerpacific are you asking me to reduce the code?

Comment: No, I'm asking you to mock the functions so that I can copy and paste your code to reproduce and debug the problem. E.g. `guidArr` is an empty array. That probably won't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jabba you wont be able to reproduce as Xrm.WebApi requires authenticated access from within Dynamics.
I thought the problem has something to do with object/array

Comment: I added a runable example and can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/dkz8pm6n/

Comment: Could you add console.log(JSON.stringify(flightName)) after console.log(flightName)

Comment: You are not awaiting the promises in your `for(var a = 0; a < values.length; a++)` loop. Thus, when you do `return flightName` the array is still empty, and thus `console.log(flightName.length)` prints `0`. The output from `console.log(flightName)` might pretend, that `flightName` contains values, but actually it does not because that `console.log` is referencing the object, which is later filled when the promises resolve. Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(flightName))` and you will see it prints just `[]` because at that moment, the array is still empty

Comment: To resolve that issue, make the first `then` handler `async` and use `await Xrm.WebApi....` or properly wrap that whole thing in a `Promise.all`

Comment: @derpirscher Thank you, that makes sense I will rework now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850877/array-length-not-reporting/69862424#comment123474085_69850877) [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850877/array-length-not-reporting/69862424#comment123474145_69850877) by [@derpircher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher) worked:

> You are not awaiting the promises in your `for(var a = 0; a < values.length; a++)` loop. Thus, when you do `return flightName` the array is still empty, and thus `console.log(flightName.length)` prints `0`. The output from `console.log(flightName)` might pretend, that `flightName` contains values, but actually it does not because that `console.log` is referencing the object, which is later filled when the promises resolve. Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(flightName))` and you will see it prints just `[]` because at that moment, the array is still empty
>
> To resolve that issue, make the first `then` handler `async` and use `await Xrm.WebApi...` or properly wrap that whole thing in a `Promise.all`